# Multiple buttons to show/hide div depending on current display

Tags: javascript

brand-spanking-new to JavaScript and am trying to implement it as part of a school assessment site.

What I'm trying to do is, using multiple buttons, change the display style of a div. The part I'm having trouble with is getting my function to either stay open (style.display = block) if a different button is pressed as the last, or close (style.display = none) if it is the same button as the previous.

The reasoning behind this is the next step will be to implement some AJAX to call different content into the div based on the same buttons. Just trying to get the basics there first. (Learning exercise)

```
    function toggle_visibility(caller) {
    var e = document.getElementById('hidden');
    var current;
    if(caller == current){
        e.style.display = 'none';
        current = 'none';
    }else{
        e.style.display = 'block';
        current = caller;
    }
```

That's my script as it is, the buttons themselves are just calling the above script with a different 'caller':

```
<button onClick="toggle_visibility('Button1')">Button1</button>
<button onClick="toggle_visibility('Button2')">Button2</button>
<button onClick="toggle_visibility('Button3')">Button3</button>
```

What am I doing wrong or missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable "current" is scoped to the function toggle_visibility.  Each time the button is clicked and the function is invoked, the "current" variable gets recreated.

You need to move the declaration for "var current;" outside of the function toggle_visibility.

When you're ready, read this for details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `current` only exists for the lifetime of that function. You will need to save the last button that was clicked in a variable outside the function (in the global scope). Just move the line
`var current;` outside of your function definition and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the statement 
    `var current;`
and it will work. You are creating local variable current in this case. If you don't use 'var' keyword, it will be created as global and will solve your problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/WG9y9/

Comment: i disagree with implicit global var creation bc i always ask myself, "did the dev really intended for this to be global?" additionally, using the 'var' keyword in the parent scope means we don't traverse all the way to window if unnecessary.